mysql replication: table structure change doesn't take effected, only records are updated, why?
use mysql v8.4.3, for both main database and slave, binlog_format set to "row",
I found any changes to the main database tables, such as add columns, create new table, doesn't reflected in the slave side, only the records update.
why? how to have all the changes include records and table structure changes reflect in slave side.
thanks advanced.

This question is about replication feature of mysql, not about programming or sw development. Please delete the question from here and re-ask it on dba.stackexchange.com sister site of SO.
